# Select em dados Json

Tags: json, postgresql

Com esse exemplo de select, obtenho a informação do account que tenho dentro do meu json:

```
 select data::json#>>'{account}' as codigo,
                  assinatura
           from assinante ce
           where assinatura in ('XXX')
```

Consigo pegar o dado que preciso do json que está assim:

```
"id":00003,
"name":"TESTE",
"account":"000000023"
```

Agora, quero pegar o código que está dentro do meu json assim:

```
"assinante":{ 
         "codigo":"0000025",
         "documento":"00000005"
 }
```

Como faço com esse mesmo modo que pego o account, mas está "fora", pegar o meu código que está dentro de assinante?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com esse select você pega tudo o que está dentro de assinante:

```
SELECT
   #suaColunaJson -> 'assinante' as assinante.
FROM
   assinante
```

Com este outro, você pega tudo o que está em código, dentro do assinante

```
SELECT
   #suaColunaJson -> 'assinante' ->> 'codigo' as codigo_assinante.
FROM
   assinante
```